# Sending a variable as a parameter in second stored proc sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, ssms

I was wondering if this was possible in SSMS.  So I have a stored proc that's within another stored proc.  Is it possible to pass the variables of one stored proc as a parameter in the second one.  I need all those variables to be stored as ONE variable in the second stored proc.   Example below.

```
Create Procedure StoreProc1_sp
@variable1 varchar(4000), 
@variable2 varchar(4000)
```

`Exec StoredProc2` --how do I pass the two above variables as ONE paramater for this

I know this probably doesn't make sense the way I'm asking it so I apologize.

Thank you,

Comment: Why would you want to pass 2 variables as one?

Comment: Why not pass in as 1 in the first place? If you concatenate those together the single parameter will need to be varchar(max).

Comment: Depends.   How will the second proc be handling the two values in the one parameter?

Comment: It needs to be passed as one because all those variable values will be stored in a column in the database for records on what was passed.  This inner stored proc will be a log stored proc that will pass information about the outter proc.  So this will be used for many different procs so it may have a different amount of variable values passed depending on the outer proc being used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to combine them but as they are strings you can concatenate them, perhaps with a seperator:

```
DECLARE @variable3 varchar(max)

SET @variable3 = @variable1 + '|' + @variable2

Exec StoredProc2 @variable3
```

In StoredProc2 you could then split them based on the '|'. **This is Hacky.**

Why not change the StoredProc2 :

```
Create Procedure StoreProc2_sp @variable1 varchar(4000), @variable2 varchar(4000)
```

and just pass Exec StoredProc2 @variable1, @variable2

?

Comment: I need them as one variable because the second (inner) proc will be inserting all those paramaters in ONE column of a table.  I didn't think to store them in another variable and pass that variable. Thanks!! I'm gonna try that.